# I try getting data from eBay from sold and auction items using webscraping but for some reason i get a NoneType error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

auctionurl = requests.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2334524.m570.l1313&_nkw=logitech&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_Auction=1&rt=nc&_odkw=Logitech&_osacat=0&LH_ItemCondition=3').text
soupauction = BeautifulSoup(auctionurl, 'lxml')


logitechauction = soupauction.find('li', class_ = "s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom s-item--watch-at-corner")
iteminfo = logitechauction.find('div', class_ = 's-item__details clearfix')
shipping = iteminfo.find('span', class_ = 's-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost').text
name = logitechauction.find('h3', class_ = 's-item__title').text
price = iteminfo.find('span', class_ = 's-item__price').text
print(name, price, shipping)


soldurl = requests.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=logitech&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_ItemCondition=3&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&LH_All=1').text
soupsold = BeautifulSoup(soldurl, 'lxml')


logitechsold = soupsold.find('li', class_ = 's-item s-item__pl-on-bottom')
soldinfo = logitechsold.find('div', class_ = 's-item__info clearfix')
soldname = soldinfo.find('h3', class_ = 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').text
soldprice = soldinfo.find('span', class_ = 's-item__price').text
print('Sold =', soldname, soldprice)
```

It prints the first "print(name, price, shipping)", but then the error happens on line 22
I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\zackz\Desktop\EbaySniping.py", line 22, in <module>
    soldname = soldinfo.find('h3', class_ = 's-item__title s-item__title--has-tags').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

When i remove the .text at the end of the line i just get

```
Sold = None $20.00
```

Which isnt the right data that it should be.

Comment: The error occurs here: `soupsold = BeautifulSoup(soldurl, 'lxml')`. Do some inspection to determine how the value of `soupurl` differs from that of `auctionurl`.  It's as if the `soldurl` isn't the object the `BeautifulSoup` class is expecting.

Comment: well i added the .text at the end of line soldurl = requests.get('https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=logitech&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_ItemCondition=3&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1&rt=nc&LH_All=1')

Comment: Code in comments are very difficult to read.  Please update the *question* accordingly.

Comment: It is 'Sold = Shop on eBay $20.00' the output you want?

Comment: No its not... plus it shouldn't be "none", and it should show the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `<li class="s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom">` doesn't contain anything, so skip it. You can do this by using `.find_all` and then get tag at second index (`[1]`):

```py
...

# the first <li class="s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom"> doesn't contain desired value, so skip it:
logitechsold = soupsold.find_all("li", class_="s-item s-item__pl-on-bottom")[1]  
soldinfo = logitechsold.find("div", class_="s-item__info clearfix")
soldname = soldinfo.find(
    "h3", class_="s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags"
).text
soldprice = soldinfo.find("span", class_="s-item__price").text
print("Sold =", soldname, soldprice)
```

Prints:

```
Logitech Streamcam 60fps 1080p  *NEW* £50.00 + £16.92 postage estimate
Sold = Logitech G Pro USB 8LO920009426 Mechanical Gaming Keyboard - Black £50.40
```